# Is there a Fortify annotation for returning a wrapped stream/connection?

Tags: java, resources, static-analysis, stream

We have a Java method that accesses a stream, wraps it, and returns it to the caller.  (We have a similar situation with a database connection.)  Fortify (the static code analyzer) reports this as an "unreleased resource" vulnerability, because we are not closing the stream.  In our case, it is up to the caller to release the resource.

Is there a way to write this or annotate this so that Fortify does not flag this method as being vulnerable, but rather flags the caller of the method (if it does not release it)?

Comment: How is the caller expected to release the resource, through the wrapper?

Comment: Good question.  In one piece of code, yes.  In another, no, they should use the standard "close" method of the returned stream.

Comment: Does it flag both cases as having this issue?  In the case where the wrapper provides a close option, does it implement `AutoClosable`?

Comment: I had to go back and look that up to be sure.  In the second case, the wrapper class is an iterator.  It implements an interface, and that interface extends AutoCloseable and Iterator.  Is it that extra layer of interface that causes the confusion?

Comment: And yes, it flags both of these cases as Unreleased Resource.  So maybe it's actually the interface that needs an annotation?

Comment: And to be clearer, it flags the class that implements this interface - let's call it StreamingIterator - as well as all three methods that return new StreamingIterator(...).  But it does not flag the callers of the three methods that accept this newly created StreamingIterator.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Fortify but if you have implemented an AutoClosable such that the `close()` method cleans up everything properly, I wouldn't expect it to be flagged this way,  In other words, I would consider it a defect or at least a limitation in the analyzer.

Comment: I have what I think is a simple example of the unreleased connection:
`public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    try {
        Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        return connection;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error creating connection " + newNum, e);
        throw e;
    }
}`
The Connection class in java.sql is AutoCloseable.  My class is not; it's a ConnectionProvider.

Comment: I don't think that code is real.  It shouldn't compile because you are throwing `Exception` but you only declare the method to throw `SQLException`.  But that aside, imagine what happens if `setAutoCommit()` throws an exception.  Your connection reference goes out of scope but the connection is never closed.

Comment: I can assure you that the code is quite real.  The only parts I removed were logger statements and metrics.  Exception is the superclass of SQLException and so will catch that as well.  That said, I think you may have found the actual problem, which is that the setAutoCommit could leak the connection.  (So obvious in retrospect!)  I'll give that a try.

Comment: You can't throw Exception if your method is declared to only throw SQLException.  You shouldn't catch Exception here anyway.

Comment: Somehow, it DOES compile.  Exception is a superclass of both checked and unchecked exceptions.  The only CHECKED exception that can be thrown is SQLException, so, I guess Java figures that out.

Comment: I'll be damned, you are right.  This must be a relatively recent feature.  It definitely wasn't that smart back in the day.  Learned something new.  Thanks.